# MomentJS inBetween always returning false

Tags: javascript, date, vue.js, momentjs, date-parsing

I am working on Vue Datatable and have a requirement to search records in between two dates.I have used moment.js **`inBetween`** function two handle this. When I hardcode the dates its returns the correct result,however the **function always seems to return `false`** with date type input. Please help

```js
var fDate = moment(this.startDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY")
var lDate = moment(this.endDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY")

tab = tab.filter(function (row) {
  var compareDate = moment(row["createdAt"]).format("DD-MM-YYYY")
  var comparison = moment(compareDate).isBetween(fDate, lDate) //  always returns false
  var t = moment("2010-10-20").isBetween("2010-10-19", "2010-10-25") //returns true
  console.log(compareDate, fDate, lDate, comparison, t)
})
```

The demo can be viewed here :https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-river-kg4bs?file=/src/App.vue:281-294

Answer (score 2):

`isBetween` take moment-like object as parameters (cited in [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)). By the way, you should only use `format` for displaying purpose

> ```
> moment().isBetween(moment-like, moment-like);
> ```

```
var tab = this.tableData
var fDate = moment(this.startDate)
var lDate = moment(this.endDate)

tab = tab.filter(function (row) {
  var compareDate = moment(row["createdAt"])
  var comparison = moment(compareDate).isBetween(fDate, lDate)

  if (comparison) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
})
```

Comment: Wow....Thanks a lot!!...although I read the doc ...I didnt really quite understand what it meant by moment-like...Now I get it. :)

Comment: @user3595524 you could think of moment-like object like object initialized by `moment(...)`

Comment: right...so putting a format('DD-MM-YYYY') was changing its type?